# Fubini Theorem for Geometric Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, infinite-product

I want to compute a geometric double integral. Does the Fubini theorem apply to a geometric integral?

[Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) allows a sum double integral to be computed as an iterated integral.

And a product (or geometric) integral can be [expressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral#Type_I) in terms of a sum integral as follows:
$$
\prod_a^bf(x)^{dx}=\exp\bigg(\int_a^b\ln f(x)dx\bigg)
$$

So, if I want to compute a geometric double integral, how can I apply Fubini's theorem?

For example, are any of these statements valid (geometric double integral = $\prod_{X \times Y}f(x,y)^{d(x,y)}$):
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \prod_{X \times Y}f(x,y)^{d(x,y)}=\prod_X \big(\prod_Yf(x,y)^{dy}\big)^{dx}&\\
& \prod_{X \times Y}f(x,y)^{d(x,y)}=\exp\bigg(\int_X\ln \big(\exp\big(\int_Y\ln f(x,y)dy\big)\big)dx\bigg)&\\
& \prod_{X \times Y}f(x,y)^{d(x,y)}=\exp\bigg(\int_{X \times Y}\ln f(x,y)d(x,y)\bigg)
\end{aligned}
$$

I would like to (know how to) compute a geometric double integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure enough you do have:

$$\begin{align}\prod_X\big(\prod_Y f(x,y)^{\mathrm d y}\big)^{\mathrm d x}~&=~ \exp\int_X\ln\prod_Y f(x,y)^{\mathrm d y}\,\mathrm d x \\ &=~ \exp\int_X\ln\exp\int_Y\ln f(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x \\ &=~ \exp\int_X\int_Y \ln f(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x  \end{align}$$

At this point you can apply Fubini's theorem, *if* the criteria is met.

$$\int_X\int_ Y \lvert \ln f(x,y)\rvert \operatorname d y\operatorname d x<\infty$$

If that is so, then indeed:

$$\prod_X\prod_Y f(x,y)~{}^{\mathrm d y}{\,}^{\mathrm d x}~=~\prod_{X\times Y} f(x,y)^{\mathrm d (x,y)}~=~\prod_Y\prod_X f(x,y){\,}^{\mathrm d x}{\,}^{\mathrm d y} \\ \exp\int_X\int_Y \ln f(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x ~=~ \exp\iint_{X\times Y}\ln f(x,y)\operatorname d (x,y)~=~\exp\int_Y\int_X \ln f(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y $$

Comment: Is that first assumption valid to make? That a geometric double integral is equal to/can be expressed as/can be computed as a geometric iterated integral (the way a (regular) sum integral can, using Fubini's theorem)?

Comment: It pretty much follows from the definition.

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit? Why does it pretty much follow from the definition (and by definition, you mean the definition of a geometric integral)? I would like more reassurance. Thank you.

Comment: More importantly however, taking your word for everything above, I would like to know, does this work for any multiple geometric integral (e.g. greater than double, like a triple or 4,5,6-integral). For example, to compute a geometric quadruple integral, could I write it as: $ \exp\big(\int_W\int_Z\int_Y\int_X\ln f(x,y,z,w)dxdydzdw\big)$?